# Make it clear that tag wiki edits are split into two separate edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I [recently edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27243312/revisions) the babelua tag wiki to fix some bad english in the excerpt (and add a small amount of additional information while I was at it.) At the same time, I noticed that there was a noticable extra space in the body, and so (in an attempt to fix multiple problems at once) removed it.

I found out later that, in fact, these edits were split up by the system - meaning that I had inadvertently submitted a single-character edit to remove a space. This was rejected, as it obviously should have been.

However, I had no way of knowing that this was the behavior of the website at the time. Could the tag wiki edit screen (at least below the rep threshold) include language to explain this?

For example, even something as simple as:

> Your edits to these two boxes will be submitted and reviewed as separate edits.

This would have saved me from inadvertently submitting a bad edit.